# SKVideoNode (embedded in SKScene) as texture for for Scene Kit Node not working

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation, scenekit, virtual-reality

I'm attempting to map a video as texture to a primitive cylinder for a VR project by using Scenekit: an SKVideoNode embedded in an SKScene as a texture for a SceneKit SCNTube object, and I just can't get video to display as a still image would. PLayground code below should generate moving video mapped to cylinder, but the mapping does not work:

**EDIT: ADDED SINGLE LINE AT END OF LISTING TO FIX. CODE BELOW SHOULD WORK**

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit      // for 3D mapping
import SpriteKit     // for SKVideoNode
import QuartzCore    // for basic animation
import XCPlayground  // for live preview
import AVFoundation  // for video playback engine

// create a scene view with an empty scene
var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene


// start a live preview of that view
XCPShowView("The Scene View", view: sceneView)

// default lighting
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

// a geometry object
var tube = SCNTube(innerRadius: 1.99, outerRadius: 2, height: 3)
var tubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: tube)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tubeNode)

// video scene


let urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp4")
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
let videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player)
let spritescene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1211, height: 431))



videoNode.size.width=spritescene.size.width
videoNode.size.height=spritescene.size.height
spritescene.addChild(videoNode)


// configure the geometry object

var myImage = UIImage.init(named: "BandImage.jpeg")

tube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents  = spritescene


// set a rotation axis (no angle) to be able to
// use a nicer keypath below and avoid needing
// to wrap it in an NSValue
tubeNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

// animate the rotation of the torus
var spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation.w") // only animate the angle
spin.toValue = 2.0*M_PI
spin.duration = 3
spin.repeatCount = HUGE // for infinity
tubeNode.addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")

// starts the video, solving the issue
    sceneView.playing = true
```

Comment: "mapping doesn't work" ?-> all black? did you try to set the width of the SKScene to 1024? did you try to force the GL renderer (see SCNView interface builder settings)?

Comment: All black, even when skscene is set to 1024. Audio plays, so I know the movie is playing, but no mapping of the texture to the surface

Comment: Interface builder? I'm generating the view from scratch in code.

Comment: Similar SKVideoNode -> SceneKit material code works for me on device... but not in the Simulator. Have you tried on device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted my code (and some sample panoramic content) on github for anyone who wants to have a working sample code or is interested in collaborating on an opensource panoramic video player:

https://github.com/jglasse/OSVR

As it turns out, it looks like simulator (and playgrounds) doesn't support this feature. Moving the above code to a project and running on a device, I finally have it working.

So the moral of the story is - **if you're using SKVideoNodes as textures for Scenekit, use an actual device for testing.**

Comment: Looks like we discovered this about the same time. Well done :)

Comment: Now it seems like the texture only updates when the object is moving - when there's no movement, while the audio continues to play, the texture does not update. have you seen this?

Comment: @jglasse did you ever get that other issue fixed? that the texture only updates when the object is moving?

Comment: No. I added an imperceptible small movement to "fix" it. Haven't tested with later Xcode builds yet to see if the bug is fixed, but will try to later today.

Comment: The audio is playing but not the video because you need to set `sceneView.playing = true`. This tells the view to update its texture regularly.

Comment: Fixed (somewhat belatedly)!