# SKVideoNode only on a small part of SCNSphere

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, video-streaming, skvideonode

I'm using SKVideoNode as a material for my sphere for 360 video, but it only renders the video on the xy positive part of the sphere, I'm streaming the video from a URL it's a `.m3u8` for reference see - [SKVideoNode as texture for SCNSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381234/skvideonode-as-texture-for-scnsphere)
Multiple people seem to be having the same issue as me

```
func makeSphere() {

    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame);
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView);

    var screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;

    var screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    var screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    sceneView.frame.size.height = screenHeight * 1;
    sceneView.frame.size.width = screenWidth * 1;
    sceneView.center.x = screenWidth * 0.5;

    let scene = SCNScene();
    sceneView.scene = scene;

    sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 5);

    sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry);

    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0);

    sphereGeometry.segmentCount = 55;

    constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: sphereNode);

    let camera = SCNCamera();
    let cameraNode = SCNNode();
    cameraNode.camera = camera;
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0);

    let light = SCNLight();
    light.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
    let lightNode = SCNNode();
    lightNode.light = light;
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0);

    cameraNode.constraints = [constraint];

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode);
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode);

    let videoMaterial = SCNMaterial();

    let path = "http://video-url.m3u8";
    let url  = NSURL(string: path);
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url!,options: nil);
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset);
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem);
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player);

    let size = CGFloat(100.0);
    let spriteScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(size,size));
    videoNode.size.width = size;
    videoNode.size.height = size;
    spriteScene.addChild(videoNode);


    videoMaterial.diffuse.contents = spriteScene;
    videoMaterial.specular.contents = UIColor.redColor();
    videoMaterial.shininess = 1.0;
    videoMaterial.doubleSided = true;

    sphereGeometry.materials = [videoMaterial];
    videoNode.play();

    }
```

You can use the code above to reproduce my problem, if it makes a difference, when I display an image it works just fine.

**EDIT**

Using `videoMaterial.diffuse.contents.transfom(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(0,-1,1));` and `videoMaterial.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.Repeat;` causes the video to be project on the lower half of the sphere, but instead of appearing correctly all I can see is stretched rings, changing the `WrapMode` makes it so that the iOS 6 screen only shows 1 colour.

Using `videoMaterial.diffuse.contents.transfom(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1,0,1));` and `videoMaterial.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.Repeat;` renders the video on the left side of the sphere, but stretches the texture / video.

Comment: Probably  not what you need but why not use a SKSNode with image transparent .PNG?  You can also scale-rotate and what not

Comment: because I need to display video, and not images @OmarGonzalezRocha

Comment: You can also add a regular Cocoa subview with a custom drawRect in the App Delegate

Comment: Curious, how did you arrive at the value of 5 for the sphere radius?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen it was just the right size, not too big & not too small, it would cover every screen as far as I know, if it were too small the corners of the screen would have a visible border, showing how big the sphere is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say specifically what's going wrong, but I have a working solution here: https://github.com/alfiehanssen/ThreeSixtyPlayer

It uses an SKVideoNode for both monoscopic and stereoscopic spherical 360 video.

I do notice that you're not setting the `position` or `anchorPoint` of your SKScene, and this is something I believe you must do in order to get the SKVideoNode (material) positioned properly.